# How to tell whereabout's my program has hung

Tags: vb.net, debugging

How can i best determine whereabouts in my code a program was up to when it hung?

I've got a misbehaving app and I can't tell whats causing the issue.

Dont want to post code and ask you guys to tell me, I'd rather figure out how to figure it out myself :)

Thanks!

Comment: learn to use the Debug tools in VS.  Breakpoints and adding `console.writeline` or `console.beep` to various places lets you know how far it gets (**dont** use MessageBox).

Comment: If you are running in the debugger press Ctrl+Break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's still responsive to the Visual Studio IDE, then just press the pause button.